# Trying to write a JS script that shows and changes certain object properties

Tags: javascript, object

So I've been doing a beginner course on Javascript.
I'm writing a script that reads an object and shows it in HTML.

I also included a method that calculates age from date of birth (DOB), because I always like to do something extra for the challenge.

Now I managed to make it so that I can change the DOB and it will also show that when changed, but the age calculation still shows the age calculated from the first DOB before I manually change it on the webpage.

I'm really lost on this one, object oriented programming is pretty hard for me, and it took me a while to get this far. Some feedback would be greatly appreciated!

```
var person = new createPerson('Stijn', 'Lammers', "1994-06-05", 0);
var getDOB = document.getElementById("inputDag");
getDOB.addEventListener("keyup", enter);

document.getElementById('knop').onclick = function(){show(person)};

function enter(event){                         //function to change the DOB value.
if(event.keyCode === 13){
    var year = document.getElementById("inputJaar");
    var month = document.getElementById("inputMaand");
    var day = document.getElementById("inputDag");
    var yearValue = +year.value;
    var monthValue = +month.value;
    var dayValue = +day.value;
    if (yearValue > 2018 || monthValue > 12 || dayValue > 31){
        alert("Incorrect date");
    }else{
        person.DOB = yearValue + "-" + monthValue + "-" + dayValue; 
    }
  }
}

function createPerson(naam, achternaam, DOB, leeftijd){
    this.naam = naam;
    this.achternaam = achternaam;
    this.DOB = DOB;
    this.leeftijd = function(){               //method to calculate age.
        var today = new Date();
        var birthDate = new Date(DOB);
        var age = +today.getFullYear() - +birthDate.getFullYear();
        var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
        if (m <0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())){
            age = age -1;
        }
        return age;
    }
}


function show(p){
    document.getElementById('tekst').innerHTML = person.naam + " " + 
    person.achternaam + " " + person.DOB + " " + person.leeftijd();
}
```

HTML body:

```
<input type="text" id="inputJaar" size="1" maxlength="4" placeholder="YYYY">
<input type="text" id="inputMaand" size="1" maxlength="2" placeholder="MM">
<input type="text" id="inputDag" size="1" maxlength="2" placeholder="DD"><br>   
<button id='knop'>klik</button>
<p id='tekst'></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your issue is related with this line inside the `leeftijd` definition:

```
var birthDate = new Date(DOB);
```

There, you pass the `DOB` parameter as a parameter, not the person's DOB (`this.DOB`).

The way you're doing it, I am **not really sure** about how you should be doing it. I **believe** this will just work:

```
function createPerson(naam, achternaam, DOB, leeftijd){
  this.naam = naam;
  this.achternaam = achternaam;
  this.DOB = DOB;
  var self = this;
  this.leeftijd = function(){               //method to calculate age.
      var today = new Date();
      var birthDate = new Date(self.DOB); // here we take the DOB of the person. The 'self' stuff feels weird, I know, google about 'self = this' to know more
      var age = +today.getFullYear() - +birthDate.getFullYear();
      var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
      if (m <0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())){
          age = age -1;
      }
      return age;
  }
}
```

Now, however, **Don't do this!**. This is not how you should be doing OOP in javascript. You're creating a `leftijd` function for every person you create. That's bad. All the person instances should have the same function to calculate their age. This is doing by adding the function to the constructor **prototype**.

Now, there are several ways to do so in javaScript. The old fashioned way is to manually setup the `leftijd`function in the `Person` prototype:

```
function Person(naam, achternaam, DOB, leeftijd){
  this.naam = naam;
  this.achternaam = achternaam;
  this.DOB = DOB;
}

Person.prototype.leftijd = function(){               //method to calculate age.
  var today = new Date();
  var birthDate = new Date(this.DOB);
  var age = +today.getFullYear() - +birthDate.getFullYear();
  var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
  if (m <0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())){
      age = age -1;
  }
  return age;
}
```

(Notice how I renamed `createPerson` to `Person`. Constructors are Uppercase in javaScript usually. Also, using `new` you know you're creating a new person, so create feels redundant)

In this code above I'm attaching the `leftijd` function to the Person's prototype, which basically means that all Person instances will have this function.

In your original code, instead, every single person created have its own `leftijd` function, which of course allocates more memory. It is a subtle difference, but you definitely don't want to add functions to `this` inside a constructor.

Now, this `prototype` stuff feels weird, and while it's good to know about it, there is the `class` syntax [which is far simpler and straightforward](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes):

```
class Person{
  constructor(naam, achternaam, DOB, leeftijd){
    this.naam = naam;
    this.achternaam = achternaam;
    this.DOB = DOB;
  }

  leftijd(){
    var today = new Date();
    var birthDate = new Date(this.DOB);
    var age = +today.getFullYear() - +birthDate.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    if (m <0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())){
        age = age -1;
    }
    return age;
  }
}
```

At the end, both ways do the same, but the class syntax hides you the `prototype` oddities and resembles more other languages like Java.

Good luck learning javaScript!

Comment: Pretty big +1 for ES6 class declaration

Comment: Thank you so much for you time! Never expected to get such a comprehensive answer. I got it fixed by just changing    new Date(DOB) to new Date(this.DOB). That's all. I gotta admit that I don't get all of your answer because I've been doing JS for only a few weeks. But I'll definitely save it for future reference.